# Facebook/Twitter Share Button in Google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, png, facebook-sharer

I want to include social media share button(facebook, twitter etc) on google charts. The idea is to get the image of chart and share it on social.

I am using this code on right click i can save google chart as image but I want to share that image on facbook how can I achieve this can you please give some ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', ],
    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],
    ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
    legend: 'none',
  };

  var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);

  // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);

 }
</script>

  <div class="fb-share-button" data-     href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"   target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse"     >Share</a></div>
```